# Failure of convergence to 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the interval $I = [0,1]$ and the sequence of functions:

$$f_n(x) = (-1)^k \ \text{for} \displaystyle \frac{k}{2^n} \le x < \frac{k+1}{2^n}  \ \text{where} \ 0 \le k < 2^n - 1$$

I want to exhibit that $f_n \not \to f \equiv 0$ strongly in $L^p[I]$ $\forall 1 \le p < \infty$

Comment: What is $\|f_n\|_p$?

Comment: Have you tried sketching the first few $f_n$’s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the $L_p$ norm of $f_n$ is $\|f_n\|_p=\left(\int_I |f_n(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}$.  If $y=1$ or $y=-1$, then $|y|^p=1$.  What is $\|f_n\|_p$?

The definition of convergence of a sequence $(f_n)$ to zero in $L^p(I)$ says that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p=0$.  Does this happen for $(f_n)$ in your question?

---

The sequence does converge weakly to $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that $\| f_n\|_p = 1$ always hence the limit cannot be 0. Also, I amended the question. I was talking about strong convergence. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, that is what I thought.  I was not confused, I just wanted to add the remark about the case of weak convergence because I think it is interesting and related; I suspect it is the motivation for cooking up this example.  I am glad you found $\|f_n\|_p$.